# pETL fails to load data to MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, petl

I'm using [petl package](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to build an ETL pipeline from Python 2.7 to MySQL5.6

My db connector is MySQLdb (mysql-python).

The following code fails to execute:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import petl as etl 

con = mdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user = '<someuser>', passwd = '<somepass>') 
cur = con.cursor()     # get the cursor

cur.execute('DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS petltest')
cur.execute('CREATE SCHEMA petltest')
cur.execute('USE petltest')

dat  = [{'id':1,'name':'One'},
 {'id':2,'name':'Two'},
 {'id':3,'name':'Three'}]

table =  etl.fromdicts(dat) # petl object

etl.todb(table,cur,'table',schema='petltest',create=True)
```

The error code is:

> ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near \'"table" (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tname
>   VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL\n)\' at line 1')

This error occurs also when trying to create table separately or running petl.appenddb

How can I fix it / overcome the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the problem was the quotes style that PETL use.
If you run:

```
cur.execute('SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES')
```

before petl sql (`petl.todb()`) statements it executes well.